# Yii2 Gridview current row values

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am new to Yii2. I have a gridview where 2 columns are auto-generated (not in model class). Every row has a button which when clicked, I want to access the current row cells values and do some calculation.

I am unable to use `$data` as it only refers to current model row. below is my code:

```
<?php 

echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $model->getInsuredCompanyVehiclesArrayDataProvider(),
    'filterModel' => $model->getInsuredCompanyVehiclesArrayDataProvider(),
    'columns' => [                                          
        [
            'label' => 'Amount',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($data) {
                return $data->rate * Yii::$app->session->get('motorInsuranceEntry')->sumInsured/100;
            },
        ],                      
        [
            'label'=>'Total',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                //return $data->rate * Yii::$app->session->get('motorInsuranceEntry')->sumInsured/100 + $model->amount;

                return '' . $column ;                       
            },
        ],                                                  
    ],
]); ?>
```

The `amount` and `Total` colum values are dynamically calculated but I am unable to access these values in other cells :(

Comment: Show how exactly these columns are generated.

Comment: I save a user form in session, where there is a numeric value input into the form. That value becomes the amount, and adding some other parameters becomes the total value. These are just numerical values, I am able to show these values in grid custom columns but I am unable to access these values in last grid cell. These value change as per grid row.

Answer (score 0):

As you might already know due to that the columns are dynamically you couldn't access them from other columns.

I would create functions for both dynamically columns (Amount and Total) in the model class to calculate your dynamically columns. And after you click your button in the row refresh the grid via pajax.

You could also add additional data to the gridview like metioned [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/1883)

by either extend your gridview model or use inline functions (req. PHP 5.3+).
But then you also have to calculate each column value again if they are completely dynamically by each row.

But i guess your simple mistake is that you use one time

```
'value' => function ($data) {
```

and the other time

```
'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
```

Both functions are correct. One time you pass the model to the function by the parameter "name" $data and the other time with the "name" $model.
Inside the function you only have access to the parameters which are passed to the function.

Your second inline function code should use $model instead of $data (first parameter name is the model).

```
 return $model->rate * Yii::$app->session->get('motorInsuranceEntry')->sumInsured/100 + $model->amount;
```

But as i mentioned i would create a function in your Model class

```
public function getAmount() {
    return $this->rate * Yii::$app->session->get('motorInsuranceEntry')->sumInsured/100;
}
```

What i don't understand is that your Total is just the amount * 2 ?
But i guess this was just some testing code.

Comment: thanks for the response, I wanted a client-side solution which I did using JQuery: $('#gridID  table tbody tr').click(function()
{
 
    $this=$(this);    
    var firstColVal= $this.find('td:first-child').text();
    var rate = $this.find('td:nth-child(2)').text().substring(0, $this.find('td:nth-child(2)').text().length - 1);
    var amount = parseInt($this.find('td:nth-child(8)').text());
    var total = parseInt($this.find('td:nth-child(9)').val()); 
    var cd = $this.find('td:nth-child(3)').html();
    var year = $this.find('td:nth-child(7)').html();  }